# 2d projection of Graphics3D object

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a Graphics3D object. I want to export it as a bitmap, and to calculate the bitmap-pixel coordinates of certain 3D points.

Mathematica obviously does a projection from 3D objects to 2D pixel coordinates when it draws the 3D graphic. How can I find out what this projection is?

I'd rather avoid doing lots of tricky geometrical calculations based on ViewVector and ViewAngle and ImageSize and BoundingBox. Is there a shortcut?

Damon.

Comment: Just curious ... Why don't let Mma do it for you?

Comment: This is for an html animation. I will create the gameboard as a Mathematica Graphics3D object, export to a bitmap, load the bitmap into an html document, then move a gamepiece around the board in Javascript.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but this sounds like you just want to export the graphics to some bitmap format like PNG.  Why not right click the 3D graphics, and choose Save Graphic As... ?  Or do an `Export["out.png", myGraphics]` ?

Comment: Let me be concrete. Let's say I generate a 3D chessboard in Mathematica, and export as png. In HTML/Javascript, I want to show a game piece moving over the chessboard. I might want to show the piece on one square or on another. How is the Javascript to know where to position the game piece?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `GeometricTransform` using the option `"Transformation" -> "Perspective"`. Suppose your projected chess board looks something like this

```
img = Image@
  Plot3D[0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Mesh -> 7, 
   MeshShading -> {{Black, White}, {White, Black}}, Boxed -> False, 
   AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {-1, -1}, None}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1, 0}]
```

[image: 3D chessboard]

To find the projection you will need the coordinates of at least 4 control points in `img` for which you know the {x,y}-coordinates. There probably are methods to have Mathematica find these coordinates automatically but you can select them manually by right-clicking on `img` and choosing "Get Coordinates". Click on the control points of your choice (in this case I chose the 4 corners of the chessboard) and
copy/paste their coordinates to a new line. You should get something like

```
controls = {{13.5`, 151.5`}, {235.5`, 68.5`}, 
   {332.5`, 206.5`}, {139.5`, 262.5`}};
```

The projection function and matrix then become

```
transform = FindGeometricTransform[controls,
   {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 8}, {0, 8}}, 
   "Transformation" -> "Perspective"][[2]]
transfMat = TranformationMatrix[transform]
```

Note that I chose the chessboard to be an 8x8 square centred at {4,4}, but you can choose any square.

A point {x,y} on the chessboard will now correspond to the point in `img` with pixel coordinates `transform[{x,y}]` or, using the projection matrix, `(transfMat[[{1,2}]].{x,y,1})/(transfMat[[3]].{x,y,1})`. So for example, to put a marker on D6, which would be at position {x,y}={4-1/2,6-1/2} in my 8x8 square, you could do something like

```
ImageCompose[img, Image[BoxMatrix[2]], Round[transform[{4 - 1/2, 6 - 1/2}]]]
```

[image: marker]

Comment: You could automate the finding of your control points by placing a red pixel in each corner in your original graph and finding them again in your img

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know. I hadn't come across FindGeometricTransform before.

Answer (score 0):

When you render your Graphics3D object, you can specify the [ViewMatrix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ViewMatrix.html) option. You can set the transformation (such as a rotation) and then the projection.

This way you can use your explicit knowledge of the projection used to calculate the correct planar coordinates.

Comment: I'm not very practised at 3D geometry. If I have a Mathematica graphic, e.g. one I've rotated with the mouse, how can I work out its ViewMatrix? AbsoluteOptions doesn't help me.